# Db2 license invalid nifi

Tags: db2, apache-nifi

We are trying to connect to db2 via nifi. Everytime we are getting license invalid error. It is saying to get db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar. We are having that jar and passing it to dbcp connection pool.

Is it that we have to add this jar to lib directory of nifi?

Comment: according to https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413734 you have to put license into classpath. so put it into NIFI/lib folder and remove it from dbcp config.

Comment: That helped, Thanks a lot